# Need help creating a dynamic navigation menu

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm creating an app for wireframing apps.  I'm working on a function for generating links from the data of the wireframed app which will consist on an unpredictable amount of sections within sections.  The interface for the sections are shaped like this

```
export interface ProjectObject{
    title: string;
    link?: string;
    summary?: string;
    description?: DescriptionPoint[];
    sections?: ProjectObject[];
    elements?: ProjectElement[];
    challenges?: ProjectChallenges[];
    feedback?: ProjectFeedbackItem[];
}
```

What I want to do is extract the `title` and `link` properties from each object and store it in a variable shaped like this

```
export interface NavLink{
    title: string;
    link: string;
    subLinks?: NavLink[]
}
```

The title and link properties are of course the properties to be extracted from each object.  The `subLinks` property is for saving nested links to be retrieved from the additional sections in the `sections` property.

I came up with the following function in an attempt to extract and form the links

```
createProjectLinks(data: ProjectObject[]){
    return data.map(a=>{
        let links: NavLink = {
            title: a.title,
            link: a.link,
            subLinks: this.createProjectLinks(a.sections)};
        return links;
    });
}
```

When passing an array of `ProjectObject`s into it I get the following error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

at first I thought it was an async issue but I created a `const` directly above the component to serve as dummy data to avoid asyncrounous problems and I'm still getting the same error passing the dummy data into the function.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way for me to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I don't use angular but when you create an `ProjectObject` I see there is a questionmark: `sections?:` which I assume means `sections` isn't required. If you pass through a ProjectObject with no sections, then `a.sections` will be undefined, so in your recursion, suddenly `data` is undefined... I hope this helps!

Comment: Can you provide the dummy data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below error is not a typescript issue, but a javascript issue

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

do this

```
createProjectLinks(data: ProjectObject[] = []){ //give default value of [] to prevent mapping on undefined data
    return data.map(a=>{
        let links: NavLink = {
            title: a.title,
            link: a.link,
            subLinks: this.createProjectLinks(a.sections)};
        return links;
    });
}
```

Comment: if data is always empty and the map doesn't run it should be an error with the way the createProjectLinks() is called.